# SQL Server Full Text search for alphanumeric string

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have encountered an odd behavior with SQL Server Full Text Search, If search term is character followed by numbers or numbers followed by character it is returning both as match although one is flipped i.e. if I search 1234FF I get a match returned with value FF1234. This only happens when search term is (char followed by num or num followed by char) if the search term is (num char num or char num char) then search only brings expected result. Don't have option of using LIKE command because of the size of table and number of columns that needs to be searched as well as search parameter can be anything from sentence to numbers and anything in between.

Here is sample query that is part of Stored Procedure.

```
SELECT * 
FROM CONTAINSTABLE (MyTable, *, '"FF7922"') AS F 
INNER JOIN MyTable C ON F.[Key] = C.ID 
ORDER BY RANK DESC;
```

When I run dm_fts_parser for searched parameter I do see why it is producing the hit but need help if there is a way to force parser to not create the second entry

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_parser ('"7922FF"',0,0,0)
keyword                         group_id        phrase_id   occurrence  special_term    display_term    expansion_type  source_term
0x003700390032003200660066          1           0           1           Exact Match     7922ff          0               7922FF
0x006E006E003700390032003200660066  1           0           1           Exact Match     nn7922ff        0               7922FF

SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_parser ('"FF7922"',0,0,0)
keyword                         group_id        phrase_id   occurrence  special_term    display_term    expansion_type  source_term
0x006600660037003900320032          1           0           1           Exact Match     ff7922          0               FF7922
0x006E006E003700390032003200660066  1           0           1           Exact Match     nn7922ff        0               FF7922

SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_parser ('"F7922F"',0,0,0)
keyword                         group_id        phrase_id   occurrence  special_term    display_term    expansion_type  source_term
0x006600370039003200320066          1           0           1           Exact Match     f7922F          0               F7922F
```

We rebuilt the catalog using the [ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-fulltext-catalog-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) command to no benefit.

Comment: I have created a table, added the values `1234ff` and `ff1234` and run this query `select * from sys.dm_fts_index_keywords( DB_ID('MyDB'), OBJECT_ID('MyTable') );` to find an entry with the value `nn7922ff` as you have found in your environment. Then I truncated the table, added the values again and the refreshed catalog did not contain that value making the predicate `CONTAINSTABLE (MyTable, *, '"FF7922"')` return only the exact match. I'm not suggesting that you truncate you production table, just sharing a behavior that might help getting to the solution.

Comment: Thanks @Ronaldo of course we can't truncate production table but we did regenerated the catalog to no benefit

Comment: @Ronaldo used this script to rebuild the catalog 
"alter full text catalog <name> rebuild"